# Chrome and/or Firefox extension to show image outside of site embedding

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

You know how sometimes on sites like Pinterest, Reddit or Tumblr, when you try to open an image in a new tab, it clumsily displays the image in the website? I was wondering if there was an extension to Chrome or Firefox that displays such images normally.

For example: [this](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fwjlhd3nk1job1.png) displays an image framed inside the Reddit website, while [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Gutenberg_Bible%2C_Lenox_Copy%2C_New_York_Public_Library%2C_2009._Pic_01.jpg/640px-Gutenberg_Bible%2C_Lenox_Copy%2C_New_York_Public_Library%2C_2009._Pic_01.jpg) opens the image directly in the browser.

I tried looking through the Chrome web store, Firefox browser add-ons, as well as googling things, but couldn't find anything.